# Clear Filter Values in BootstrapTable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrapTable with a filter, with server-side data.

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover" id="position-list"
data-toggle="table" 
data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, ALL]"
data-url="/getData.jsp"
data-side-pagination="server"
data-pagination="true" 
data-click-to-select="true"
data-id-field="id"
data-show-footer="false"   
data-minimum-count-columns="2"                           
data-height="550" 
data-filter-control="true" 
data-filter-show-clear="true"
>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th data-sortable="true" data-field="Status" data-filter-control="select">Status</th>
      ....
```

The line `data-filter-show-clear="true"` adds a button to the bootstrapTable, which works great. 
Here is a demo from the developer http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#extensions/filter-control.html

The problem is that I have my own button somewhere else on the screen, which I would like to activate the clear filter, and I do not want this default button.

One option I have tried is to attach the following code to my button

```
 $('.form-control').val('');
 $('#position-list').bootstrapTable('refresh');
```

However it doesn't work - by debugging bootstrap-table.js I can see that filterColumnsPartial is not reset, and so my manual filter selection is ignored.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix this issue by doing this trick:

```
$('#yourCustomButtonId').on('click', function(){ $('.filter-show-clear').trigger('click') });
```

And if you need to hide button you can use this:

```
.filter-show-clear {visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: -9999px}
```

This will fix issue.

Note: about your code and why is not work, that since the remove function is remove filter, and clear cookie and reset filters ..etc

```
BootstrapTable.prototype.clearFilterControl = function () {
        if (this.options.filterControl && this.options.filterShowClear) {
            var that = this,
                cookies = collectBootstrapCookies(),
                header = getCurrentHeader(that),
                table = header.closest('table'),
                controls = header.find(getCurrentSearchControls(that)),
                search = that.$toolbar.find('.search input'),
                timeoutId = 0;

            $.each(that.options.valuesFilterControl, function (i, item) {
                item.value = '';
            });

            setValues(that);

            // Clear each type of filter if it exists.
            // Requires the body to reload each time a type of filter is found because we never know
            // which ones are going to be present.
            if (controls.length > 0) {
                this.filterColumnsPartial = {};
                $(controls[0]).trigger(controls[0].tagName === 'INPUT' ? 'keyup' : 'change');
            } else {
                return;
            }

            if (search.length > 0) {
                that.resetSearch();
            }

            // use the default sort order if it exists. do nothing if it does not
            if (that.options.sortName !== table.data('sortName') || that.options.sortOrder !== table.data('sortOrder')) {
                var sorter = header.find(sprintf('[data-field="%s"]', $(controls[0]).closest('table').data('sortName')));
                if (sorter.length > 0) {
                    that.onSort(table.data('sortName'), table.data('sortName'));
                    $(sorter).find('.sortable').trigger('click');
                }
            }

            // clear cookies once the filters are clean
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
                if (cookies && cookies.length > 0) {
                    $.each(cookies, function (i, item) {
                        if (that.deleteCookie !== undefined) {
                            that.deleteCookie(item);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, that.options.searchTimeOut);
        }
    };
```

I tired to find a clear button option, but Im not find one, so that you need to trigger current filter or build your clear function dependence of core prototype or any way else....

Comment: Thanks very much! I will check it out in the office tomorrow... If you have time can you check out my other question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033993/programmatically-filling-combo-boxes-in-bootstrap-v4-datatables

Comment: Am checking out your idea but I am getting 'out of stack space' from the console. even if I just invoke $('.filter-show-clear').click() directly.  Clicking directly on the button works. Any ideas?

Comment: Mmm, Sorry mate, I dont have an idea about this...:'(

Comment: My bad. I had added the .filter.show.clear to my button as well, creating an infinite loop...

Comment: Almost there! Everything works, the button was hidden, my own button works. The only problem was that there was a large top margin caused by the invisible button. So I replaced your .css suggestion with `.filter-show-clear {display:none}` which diminished the margin somewhat (but not totally)

Comment: And adding `.fixed-table-toolbar {display:none}` to the css gets rid of the extra top margin entirely.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Cleaner solution:

```
$('#position-list').bootstrapTable('filterBy', {});
```

Comment: As of bootstrapTable 1.19 (at least), this gives an error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

> $('#yourCustomButtonId').on('click', function(){ $('table').bootstrapTable('clearFilterControl') }); })